# Area under the power of a Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I just want to confirm one operation I am doing. If $\beta>0$ and $p(x|\theta)$ is a factorized multivariate Gaussian distribution with dimensionality $d$ and distribution given by:

$$p(x|\theta)=\Big[\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)\Big)\Big]^{d}$$

I would like to compute the are under the following curve,expressed through:

$$\int \Big[\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)\Big)\Big]^{d\beta}dx$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that you mean the integral of the distribution over $R^n$, then you can use a substitution of $$x_i = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{d\beta}}y_i+\mu$$ to transform the integral into a standard form:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)^{d\beta}\frac{\sigma^n}{(d\beta)^{n/2}}\int\exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^Ty)d^ny$$

The additional constant in the front comes from the Jacobian of the transformation. This integral has a solution (per Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) of:

$$ \int\exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^Ty)d^ny = (2\pi)^{n/2}$$

Comment: the distribution is over dimensionality $\mathbb{R}^d$ as we have a $d-$dimensional factorized Gaussian distribution, with distribution given by the first equation.

Comment: I see, I'll update with n=d.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to figure out why this derivation does not give the same result. Maybe you could illustrate me:

$\int p(x|\theta)^\beta=\int \Big[(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-d0.5}\exp\Big(\frac{d}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)\Big)\Big]^\beta=\\
(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-d0.5\beta}\int\exp\Big(\frac{d\beta}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)\Big)=\\
(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-d0.5\beta}\int\exp\Big(\frac{d}{2\sigma^2\beta^{-1}}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)\Big)=\\
(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-d0.5\beta}(2\pi\sigma^2\beta^{-1})^{-d0.5}=\beta^{0.5d}(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-0.5d(1+\beta)}$

Comment: I just move the $beta$ coefficient down and assume that we have a Gaussian with variance = $\sigma^2\beta^{-1}$